# Quickblox webrtc video call receive method is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, quickblox

Quickblox webrtc video call  receive method is not called .I am call to someone he accept the call and we can communicate but while he is calling me i am not geting that call.
`

```
- (void)didReceiveNewSession:(QBRTCSession *)session userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

if (self.session ) {

    [session rejectCall:@{@"reject" : @"busy"}];
    return;
}

self.session = session;

[QBRTCSoundRouter.instance initialize];

NSParameterAssert(!self.nav);

IncomingCallViewController *incomingViewController =
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IncomingCallViewController"];
incomingViewController.delegate = self;
incomingViewController.session = session;
incomingViewController.usersDatasource = self.dataSource;

self.nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:incomingViewController];
[self presentViewController:self.nav animated:NO completion:nil];
 }
```

Comment: Did you add "[QBRTCClient.instance addDelegate:self];"

Comment: yes i add it in view will appear                                    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [QBRTCClient.instance addDelegate:self];
    
}

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The Quickblox webrtc video call receive method only called when the user is online so make sure you add in Your -

```
(Void)ViewDidLoad{

[QBRequest logInWithUserLogin:@"xxxxxx"
                         password:@"xxxxx"
                     successBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response, QBUUser * _Nullable user)
     {
}];
[[QBChat instance] connectWithUser:self.user completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"User%@",self.user);
 }];
}
```

It will be called.